# When does a new year start for stats?

Tags: support, reputation-leagues

On your profile you can see top x% of this year, if you click on it it shows the year 2016. when is it going to start showing the stats for 2017?

Comment: For me, it does now.

Comment: [Probably relevant](https://twitter.com/nick_craver/status/815381121630400512)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like the leagues [have caught up](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/year/stackoverflow/2017-01-01).  It may just have taken a while for the script to populate this to run.